# Create a DynamoDB table from json

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I was wondering if its possible to create a dynamodb table from the table definition json itself? I've looked into the aws cli tool and I couldnt find any way of doing this. Just wondering if it's possible.

```
aws dynamodb create-table file://tabledenifision.json
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean you "had no luck"? Did you get an error, and what did the error say? What is inside the `tabledenifision.json` file?

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant I couldnt find any way of doing it. There's no command to read in an entire table schema as json

Comment: The first two searches on Google for "aws create table json" seem really promising, both directly from AWS itself. [1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/shorthand-syntax.html) [2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/create-table.html).  Do neither of these accomplish what you want?

Comment: No, neither of the links accomplish it.

Comment: If you don't know what to put inside `tabledefinition.json` file, you might use https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-table-schema-design-tool/. It helps me a lot.

Comment: Additional answers on this duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100210/how-to-export-an-existing-dynamo-table-schema-to-json#answer-67695947

Answer (score 39):

I found your unanswered question today, and kept looking until I found an answer. Probably too late for you but may help others.

```
aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://tabledefinition.json
```

This command expects a json object in the file in the format outlined by the following command:

```
aws dynamodb create-table --generate-cli-skeleton
```

This approach seems to work with many aws commands.

Comment: is it possible to reverse-engineer the json file from an existing dynamodb table?

Comment: @AnthonyKong Yes, use aws dynamo describe-table --table-name existing_table_name and the output is JSON `Table` property is in the same format

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Python script for this. My version is for yaml, but can easily be adapted to json.

Single dependency for parsing the template, with thanks to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914422/parse-an-aws-cloudformation-template-with-the-pyyaml-library)

`pip install cfn_flip`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import time
import yaml
from cfn_tools import load_yaml, dump_yaml

template_file = open('./template.yaml')
template = load_yaml(template_file.read())

for resource_key in template["Resources"]:
  resource = template["Resources"][resource_key]
  if resource["Type"] != 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table':
    continue
  
  table_name = resource["Properties"]["TableName"]
  print(f'Creating table "{table_name}"')
  
  table_definition = template["Resources"][resource_key]["Properties"]
  time_to_live_definition = table_definition.get("TimeToLiveSpecification")
  if time_to_live_definition:
    # TimeToLiveSpecification is not accepted by create-table, it is a separate command
    del(table_definition["TimeToLiveSpecification"])

  subprocess.run(["aws", "dynamodb", "create-table", "--cli-input-yaml",dump_yaml(table_definition)])
  if time_to_live_definition:
    time_to_live_definition = {
      "TableName": table_name,
      "TimeToLiveSpecification": time_to_live_definition
    }
    subprocess.run(["aws", "dynamodb", "update-time-to-live", "--cli-input-yaml", dump_yaml(time_to_live_definition)])
  
  # Tables are created asynch, give some time to complete
  time.sleep(1)
```

The sleep at the end is for following warning mentioned in the help of `create-table`. I have only tested this locally so far, so a smarter way to wait for completion might be needed.

> You can optionally define secondary indexes on the new table, as part
> of the "CreateTable" operation. If you want to create multiple tables
> with secondary indexes on them, you must create the tables
> sequentially. Only one table with secondary indexes can be in the
> "CREATING" state at any given time.