# Creating dynamo db tables in local host using json file

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to create dynamodb tables in localhost I have downloaded my remote dynamodb tables using this script.

https://github.com/bchew/dynamodump

This script I got from this answer over here. 
[How to export an existing dynamo table schema to json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100210/how-to-export-an-existing-dynamo-table-schema-to-json?rq=1)

And I got a local back up of all the tables in my local machine Now I want to create those tables in my dynamodb local system for that reason I am uploading my tables to local DB using this command.

```
sudo aws  dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file:///home/evbooth/Desktop/dynamo/table/dynamodump/dump/admin/schema.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

But I am getting an error like this.

```
Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in input: "AttributeDefinitions"
Missing required parameter in input: "TableName"
Missing required parameter in input: "KeySchema"
Missing required parameter in input: "ProvisionedThroughput"
Unknown parameter in input: "Table", must be one of: AttributeDefinitions, TableName, KeySchema, LocalSecondaryIndexes, GlobalSecondaryIndexes, ProvisionedThroughput, StreamSpecification, SSESpecification
```

The downloaded json file is like this.

```
{
  "Table": {
    "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:xxxx:table/admin", 
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "userid", 
        "AttributeType": "S"
      }
    ], 
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
      "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0, 
      "WriteCapacityUnits": 1, 
      "ReadCapacityUnits": 1
    }, 
    "TableSizeBytes": 0, 
    "TableName": "admin", 
    "TableStatus": "ACTIVE", 
    "TableId": "fd21aaab-52fe-4f86-aba6-1cc9a7b17417", 
    "KeySchema": [
      {
        "KeyType": "HASH", 
        "AttributeName": "userid"
      }
    ], 
    "ItemCount": 0, 
    "CreationDateTime": 1403367027.739
  }
}
```

How can i fix this? I really got annoyed with aws dont have much idea about dynamo db as well

Comment: It looks as though the aws command is expecting the contents of "Table" as the top-level input, but instead it's seeing this thing called "Table" that it doesn't know what to do with. Try removing line 2 and the penultimate line in your example JSON file and see what happens.

Comment: @wolfson109 The JSON i have formatted is like this {
    `"AttributeDefinitions": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "userid", 
        "AttributeType": "S"
      }
    ], 
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
      "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0, 
      "WriteCapacityUnits": 1, 
      "ReadCapacityUnits": 1
    }, 
    "TableSizeBytes": 0, 
    "TableName": "admin", 
    "TableStatus": "ACTIVE", 
    "TableId": "fd21aaab-52fe-4f86-aba6-1cc9a7b17417", 
    "KeySchema": [
      {
        "KeyType": "HASH", 
        "AttributeName": "userid"
      }
    ]
}`

Comment: But it gives error `Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "TableSizeBytes", must be one of: AttributeDefinitions, TableName, KeySchema, LocalSecondaryIndexes, GlobalSecondaryIndexes, ProvisionedThroughput, StreamSpecification, SSESpecification
Unknown parameter in input: "TableStatus", must be one of: AttributeDefinitions, TableName, KeySchema, LocalSecondaryIndexes, GlobalSecondaryIndexes, ProvisionedThroughput, StreamSpecification, SSESpecification
Unknown parameter in input: "TableId", must be one of: AttributeDefinitions, `

Comment: `TableName, KeySchema, LocalSecondaryIndexes, GlobalSecondaryIndexes, ProvisionedThroughput, StreamSpecification, SSESpecification
Unknown parameter in ProvisionedThroughput: "NumberOfDecreasesToday", must be one of: ReadCapacityUnits, WriteCapacityUnits`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@wolfson thank you for your suggestion after working some time removing these stuff from the schema helped me to create a table anyway. 
I removed

```
1)"Table": {
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:xxxx:table/admin",

2)"NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
3), 
        "ItemCount": 0, 
        "CreationDateTime": 1403367027.739
      }
4)"TableSizeBytes": 0,
5) 
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE", 
        "TableId": "fd21aaab-52fe-4f86-aba6-1cc9a7b17417",
```

The resultant json is like but i forced to do this for all the tables and made me to do the create table operation n number of tables.

```
 {       
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "userid", 
            "AttributeType": "S"
          }
        ], 
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {

          "WriteCapacityUnits": 1, 
          "ReadCapacityUnits": 1
        }, 

        "TableName": "admin",
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "KeyType": "HASH", 
            "AttributeName": "userid"
          }
        ]
    }
```

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create the table locally in DynamoDB by removing this completely:

> ```
> "BillingModeSummary": {
>     "BillingMode": "PROVISIONED",
>     "LastUpdateToPayPerRequestDateTime": 0
>   }
> ```

Once the table got created I looked at the table meta information, strangely it contains this:

```
"BillingModeSummary": {
    "BillingMode": "PROVISIONED",
    "LastUpdateToPayPerRequestDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
```

I went back and tried to create table using the format as shown above. However it failed. Bottomline just remove `"BillingModeSummary"` and voila the table got created! :-)