# Uploading json data to local dynamo db with aws cli

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

This question is the continuation of this question. 
[Creating dynamo db tables in local host using json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606035/creating-dynamo-db-tables-in-local-host-using-json-file)

The scrip which is being mentioned in the above question is created a data folder which contains a JSON now I want to upload the same to my dynamo DB local how can I do that?

The json is like this.

```
    {
      "Items": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "S": "true"
          },
          "ccode": {
            "S": "91"
          },
          "userid": {
            "S": "call1test@gmail.com"
          },
          "pgrad": {
            "S": "CA"
          },
          "experience": {
            "N": "10"
          },
          "lname": {
            "S": "test"
          },
          "phone": {
            "S": "9945134254"
          },
          "location": {
            "S": "bangalore"
          },
          "fname": {
            "S": "test"
          },
          "grad": {
            "S": "Not Pursuing Graduation"
          }
        }
    ]
}
```