# Creating dynamoDB table from JSON file

Tags: python, json, amazon-dynamodb

I have a massive JSON file that has many items. I am trying to create a DynamoDB table based on the JSON file without having to enter each individual attribute. I have tried the following with the AWSCLi

```
aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://tabledefinition.json
aws dynamodb create-table --generate-cli-skeleton
```

as mentioned here ( [Create a DynamoDB table from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334621/create-a-dynamodb-table-from-json) ). I have also looked at a couple python libraries (ex https://github.com/jlafon/PynamoDB) that does not have an option. All the json files are stored in an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**

This is a very generic class as OP doesn't have specific table definition mentioned.

The table definition JSON is not equal to the normal data JSON. Please see the example of table definition JSON. You need to create similar one to create the table using JSON and AWS CLI.

```
{
    "TableName": "MusicCollection2",
    "KeySchema": [
      { "AttributeName": "Artist", "KeyType": "HASH" },
      { "AttributeName": "SongTitle", "KeyType": "RANGE" }
    ],
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
      { "AttributeName": "Artist", "AttributeType": "S" },
      { "AttributeName": "SongTitle", "AttributeType": "S" }
    ],
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
      "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
      "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
    }
}
```

**Data Load Options:-**

**Option 1:-**

Once the table is created, you can write [Python code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.02.html) to load the data into DynamoDB. Please note that you need to map each attributes on JSON to attributes on DynamoDB table (or) store the JSON as MAP on DynamoDB table. This depends on your use case i.e. how you are going to use the data loaded into DynamoDB table.

**Option 2:-**

You can use [AWS Data Pipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-console-start.html) to create the mapping and load the data into DynamoDB table. If it is a one time load, you can delete the Data Pipeline once the load is complete.

Comment: So I do not need a definition for each item in my json string in the create table step correct?

Comment: Yes, it is not required.

Comment: You might also use https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-table-schema-design-tool/ to create table definition JSON for you. The syntax is rather complex and personally it helps me a lot.